# Postgresql Schema not found after moving to Amazon AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, rds, apartment-gem

I have a multi-tenant rails 3.2 app that uses postgresql 9.3.5 and apartment gem. Everything works fine in my local and even when I ran "rails s -e production" it still works. Also when I use "rails c production" in AWS, its working. I can intercat with the db via rails console. I'm using VPC. My rails app is in ec2 and the db is in RDS.

When I deploy to AWS I get this error in the browser.

```
Apartment::SchemaNotFound
One of the following schema(s) is invalid: ec2-54-169-xxx-xxx, "public"
```

Passenger Logs:

```
App 9023 stderr: Apartment::SchemaNotFound (One of the following schema(s) is invalid: ec2-54-169-xxx-xxx, "public"):
App 9023 stderr:   apartment (0.25.2) lib/apartment/adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:92:in `rescue in connect_to_new'
App 9023 stderr:   apartment (0.25.2) lib/apartment/adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:85:in `connect_to_new'
App 9023 stderr:   apartment (0.25.2) lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:100:in `switch'
App 9023 stderr:   apartment (0.25.2) lib/apartment/elevators/generic.rb:20:in `call'
```

ec2-54-169-xxx-xxx contains the ip of my ec2 I just replaced some with x.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to fix it. I was using the Public DNS given by AWS to test. Looks like that was the error because my app was listening to the subdomain. When I tried using the ip of the EC2 it worked. So I worked on the Route53 right away to access it via domain name on the browser, then it already worked.